# How to use bootstrap alerts instead of jqgrid alerts

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, alert

How to replace jqgrid alert messages(successfully added,deleted) to bootstrap alerts?I am using JQGRID 5.2.1. As we use following code in jqgrid for alerts

```
 if (response.responseText) {  
         alert(response.responseText);  
                        }
```

Comment: You should *contact the developer* of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use. Alternativ fork of jqGrid, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, allows to define a custom function `$.jgrid.defaults.fatalError` and jqGrid calls the function *instead of* `alert`. Close functionality should provide Guriddo jqGrid to be able to implement your requirements.

Comment: @Aishwarya  instead of alert you can use the command which use the Bootstrap modal. [Look here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) how to call this instead of alert()

Comment: @Oleg If I want to use bootstrap alerts then what I need to do in free jqgrid?Can you please explain it I am new to it

Comment: @Tony we don't want to use modal because its look and feel is different..Do we have any other option for that?Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to remind, that `alert` will be used by free jqGrid extremely seldom and only in **critical** situations, for example, if the grid can't be created at all.

On the other side, one could have the requirement don't use `alert` as common policy of a company and as common requirement to every JavaScript modules. It will corresponds to the polity of some web browsers (see [the article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy) for example).

One more example of requirement to replace `alert` usage will be creating unit tests, which reproduces some errors explicitly. It would be helpful to test the existence of an error only without displaying blocking `alert`.

In any way free jqGrid allows to define `$.jgrid.defaults.fatalError` method, which will be used by jqGrid *instead of* `alert`. For example, one can use the code like below

```
$.jgrid.defaults = $.jgrid.defaults || {};
$.jgrid.defaults.fatalError = function (errorText) {
    $("body").prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">' +
        '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>' +
        '<h4 class="alert-heading">Error</h4>' +
        '<p>' + errorText + '</p>' +
      '</div>').alert()
        .on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        })          
};
```

before creating of any grid.

https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/c70pfv6r/ is a simple grid, which uses Bootstrap CSS. I included `$.jgrid.defaults.fatalError` in the code, but it will be not really used. I modified the demo to include `colNames` parameter, which length don't corresponds the length of `colModel` parameter: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/c70pfv6r/1/. jqGrid can't create the grid and it uses `alert` in such cases. One the other side one will see the following div instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much easer way to do this. In case of Guriddo jqGrid as declared in the question it is possible to use the build in common function $.jgrid.info_dialog like this

```
if (response.responseText) {  
         $.jgrid.info_dialog('My Title', response.responseText, 'Close', { styleUI : 'Bootstrap'});
```

More on the common Guriddo jqGrid functions you can [look here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/common-functions/#list-of-common-objects)